# Page Speed recognizes expiers headers, but YSlow doesn't

Tags: http-headers, iis-6

We're running IIS6 on Windows Server 2003. Our site is written in ASP.NET.
 We configured our site to expire headers after 7 days. While Page Speed gives us a check for "Leverage browser caching", YSlow gives us an F on "Add Expires headers".
How can that be?
An example page can be found [here](http://test.clickit3.ort.org.il/schooltheme2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't see expiry or max-age headers either looking at either /schooltheme2010 nor Apps/WW/Page.aspx?ws=20068125-bc31-475c-906f-8b63aab03be3&page=3e96fc8a-0b11-410b-ade1-e9036203dbd2 (which is where I ended up after that).
2. Remember that Page Speed and YSlow are tools that offer guidelines (and I severely frown on YSlow's advice to turn off e-tags as 99.9999% of the time that makes things worse). You need to look at what's actually happening in detail yourself. Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or something like that to view what is going on.
3. If Page Speed is saying "leverage browser caching" what makes you think it's seeing expires headers? Sounds to me like it's saying it doesn't.
4. Expires is overridden by max-age, which has a few advantages. There's no reason why you can't use both though.

Comment: Regarding 3: Page Speed gives me a green check mark near the words "leverage browser caching", which means that it's ok (before I turned on expires headers on IIS, it gave me a red exclamation mark near it).
Regarding 1: If I turned on the expires headers on the site in the IIS, how come it's not sent (I also don't see it in Fiddler)? What else am I supposed to do?

Comment: What have you set on IIS? Also, what have you set on the aspx pages used, as they override IIS settings.

Comment: I do see the headers now in Fiddler. Also, I discovered that the expire header is added only to some folders in our project, so I moved the images to the folder that does get the header, and now YSlow gives us a higher grade. Thanks a lot for your leading questions